# Applying decorators to decorators

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, flask, decorator

I've written two decorators for my Flask GAE app:

```
def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if (not users.get_current_user()):
            return redirect(home_url)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function

def registration_required():
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if(not is_registered_user(users.get_current_user().user_id())):
            return redirect(user_reg_url)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

For most pages in the app, the user needs to be both logged in and registered, so the view handlers use both decorators. For example,

```
@app.route(some_page)
@login_required
@registration_required
def some_page_view():
    # whatever code here
```

I think it would make more sense from a design standpoint if the implementation of `registration_required` was itself decorated with `login_required`, since it needs the user to be logged in for it to check if they're registered. What I've tried is this:

```
@login_required
def registration_required():
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if(not is_registered_user(users.get_current_user().user_id())):
            return redirect(user_reg_url)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function
```

Then it could be used alone on view handlers, like this:

```
@app.route(some_page)
@registration_required
def some_page_view():
    # whatever code here
```

However, when I try, I get the error `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__name__'`. Is there something special I have to do to decorate decorators in Flask?

Comment: Do you really want to decorate decorators or don't you rather want to decorate decorated functions?  The difference is relevant of course.

Comment: And please fix the indentation of the code you posted.

Comment: The question is about how to decorate decorators. I'm well aware that you can apply multiple decorators to a regular function.

Comment: I've fixed the indentation. I didn't realize it got mangled when I copied from my editor.

Comment: Now I understand what you want (by help of the first answer ;-).  Please provide your code.  You just said "when I try" but you don't specify the syntax you used to "try" it.

Comment: I added more code to clarify.

Comment: Hmm, I expected to get the code which represents the trial of decorating the decorator.  I still don't see that, but I guess it doesn't matter anymore if your problem is already solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to simply invoke the decorator you want to wrap on the wrapper you are returning:

```
def registration_required():
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if(not is_registered_user(users.get_current_user().user_id())):
            return redirect(user_reg_url)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return login_required(decorated_function)
```

This works because the decorator syntax is just a shorthand:

```
@decorator
def some_func():
    pass
```

is the same as:

```
def some_func():
    pass

some_func = decorator(some_func)
```

And:

```
@decorator2
@decorator1
def some_func():
    pass
```

Is the same as:

```
def some_func():
    pass

some_func = decorator2(decorator1(some_func))
```